# R Shiny - how to check if there are any invalidated reactives

Tags: shiny

The use case is an R Shiny app where I want to show a message when all the reactives are no longer invalidated, i.e. the app has been loaded fully.  As most of the reactives are in modules, is there a global value that indicates this?